# What do I have to specify to make set-culture set a default of 24 hours rather than 12 hours with AM/PM

Tags: powershell, i18n

I am trying to change my environment with Powershell so that time is displayed in 24 hours format without AM/PM.

This is what I do:

```
$culture = get-culture

$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = 'HH:mm'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.pmDesignator     = ''

set-culture $culture
```

This gets rid of the AM/PM designator but still displays hours in the 0..12 range rather than in the expected 0..23 range. So what do I need to in order to have hours displayed in 24 hours format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The short time format of your user locale on the system is stored under the registry key `HKCU:\Control Panel\International` in the value `sShortTime`. You can edit the data of this value by the following PowerShell command:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' -Name 'sShortTime' -Value 'HH:mm'
```

The change will be visible after the UI updates, e. g. when a minute passes. You might want to change `sTimeFormat`, too, as it corresponds to the `LongTimePattern` property.

---

[`Set-Culture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture) is designed to set/load predefined objects of the `CultureInfo` class. You normally use it like this:

```
Set-Culture -CultureInfo 'en-US'
```

If you retrieve a `CultureInfo` object and then change its properties, you do not create a new `CultureInfo` object. It especially still has the name of a predefined `CultureInfo` object (e. g. `en-US`). If you use such a modified `CultureInfo` object with `Set-Culture`, I think the behaviour is undefined (I'm not sure). You can see that it accepts to overwrite the `LongTimePattern` property, but not the `ShortTimePattern` property. I don't know if this is a bug or just undefined.

Nevertheless, you can define your own custom `CultureInfo` object, derive it from a predefined object, and use this on your system instead. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netcore-3.1#custom-cultures). An example implementation in C# is shown [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?view=netframework-4.8#examples). You can translate this to PowerShell like follows (execute it with administrative privileges):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName sysglobl
$carib = New-Object -TypeName System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder -ArgumentList @('en-US-Custom', [System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionModifiers]::None)
$carib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US'))
$carib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo((New-Object -TypeName System.Globalization.RegionInfo -ArgumentList 'en-US'))
$carib.GregorianDateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'HH:mm:ss'
$carib.GregorianDateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = 'HH:mm'
$carib.Register()
```

After that, you have a custom `CultureInfo` object - named `en-US-Custom` - available on your system and you can set it with:

```
Set-Culture -CultureInfo 'en-US-Custom'
```

If you want to delete your custom `CultureInfo` object, you can do it like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName sysglobl
[System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder]::Unregister('en-US-Custom')
```

Now you can decide, if you want to define a custom `CultureInfo` object or just change one or two values in the registry. In your case, I recommend to change the registry, as this is exactly what happens, when you change the short time pattern in the GUI:

[image]

Comment: Your explanation thoroughly explains what I didn't understand about the get/set-culture couple. Thanks for all your effort.